# Why is vector(size) slower than new[]?

Tags: c++, stl, memory-management

I was benchmarking some STL algorithms, and I was surprised by the time taken by the following code: (I measured the g++ compiled code [no optimizations] with the `time` command)

```
#include <vector>
struct vec2{
    int x, y;
    vec2():x(0), y(0) {}
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    const int size = 200000000;
    std::vector<vec2> tab(size); //2.26s
//  vec2* tab = new vec2[size]; //1.29s
//  tab[0].x = 0;
//  delete[] tab;
    return 0;
}
```

The time taken by a vector initialization is 2.26s while a `new` (and `delete`) takes 1.29s. What is the vector ctor doing that would take so much longer? `new[]` calls the constructor on every element, just as the `vector` ctor would, right?

I then compiled with -O3, it went all faster, but there was still a gap between the two codes. (I got respectively 0.83s and 0.75s)

Any ideas?

Comment: Besides what DeadMG said, it makes no sense to do "one shot" benchmarks (and, as you saw, benchmarks without optimizations), because there are statistical fluctuations due to cache misses & co. You should repeat the benchmark a significant number of times (into the same process), measure the time of each test and calculate the mean and the standard deviation. Only after you get this data you can do a sensible comparison: if the two times differ of less than the uncertainty of your measure (calculated combining the two standard deviations in RSS) there's no significant difference.

Comment: Note that, since your code actually only references `tab[0]`, it is perfectly legal for the compiler to allocate just that single element. In fact, since you only write into `tab[0]` and never read the value back, and it's not `volatile`, it is perfectly legal for the compiler to completely remove the body of `main()` in the output, as it has no observable side effects.

Comment: Tried this test in Visual Studio, got the opposite results (best time for vector about 10% better), but the measurement noise (~20-25%) was bigger than the difference. So these measurements are really moot when it comes to real-life applications.

Comment: "I was benchmarking...no optimizations" Then it's entirely pointless. This is like asking which of two cars has a higher top speed...while forcing them to stay in neutral.

Comment: @GMan : There is indeed a use in benchmarking non-optimized code : when I debug my programm, the code is not optimized, and it's always good to debug faster. But I agree that the most relevant is to bench optimized code.

Comment: @Pavel : I am aware that the compiler could remove usuned code with optims enabled, but here, time measurement clearly shows that it is still doing something.

Comment: @Matteo : I gave you a mean of exec time over ~20 shots, forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The speed will depend on implementation, but most likely reason for the vector being slower is that vector cannot default-construct its elements. Vector elements are always copy-constructed. For example

```
std::vector<vec2> tab(size);
```

is in reality interpreted as

```
std::vector<vec2> tab(size, vec2());
```

i.e. the second argument gets its value from default argument. The vector then allocates raw memory and *copies* this default-constructed element passed from the outside into every element of the new vector (by using copy-constructor). This could be generally slower than default-constructing each element directly (as `new[]` does).

To illustrate the difference with a code sketch, `new vec2[size]` is roughly equivalent to

```
vec2 *v = (vec2 *) malloc(size * sizeof(vec2));

for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  // Default-construct `v[i]` in place
  new (&v[i]) vec2();

return v;
```

while `vector<vec2>(size)` is roughly equivalent to

```
vec2 source; // Default-constructed "original" element

vec2 *v = (vec2 *) malloc(size * sizeof(vec2));

for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  // Copy-construct `v[i]` in place
  new (&v[i]) vec2(source);

return v;
```

Depending on the implementation, the second approach might turn out slower.

The two-times difference in speed is hard to justify though, but benchmarking non-optimized code makes no sense either. The much less significant difference you observed with optimized code is exactly what one might reasonably expect in this case.

Comment: I bet the compiler inlined the default constructor, possibly special-casing the "initialize memory block to zero" operation.

Comment: It might be good to note that in C++0x, calling the one argument constructor of vector default-initializes the elements it creates, instead of copying the "template".

Answer (score 7):

Both versions initialize the memory.

As several people have pointed out, the vector uses copy construction while the array uses the default constructor.  Your compiler appears to optimize the latter better than the former.

Note that in Real Life, you rarely want to initialize such a huge array in one fell swoop. (What use are a bunch of zeroes?  Obviously you intend to put something else in there eventually...  And initializing hundreds of megabytes is very cache-unfriendly.)

Instead, you would write something like:

```
const int size = 200000000;
std::vector<vec2> v;
v.reserve(size);
```

Then when you are ready to put a real element into the vector, you use `v.push_back(element)`.  The `reserve()` allocates memory without initializing it; the `push_back()` copy-constructs into the reserved space.

Alternatively, when you want to put a new element into the vector, you can use `v.resize(v.size()+1)` and then modify the element `v.back()`.  (This is how a "pool allocator" might work.)  Although this sequence will initialize the element and then overwrite it, it will all happen in the L1 cache, which is almost as fast as not initializing it at all.

So for a fair comparison, try a large vector (with `reserve`) vs. an array for creating a sequence of non-identical items.  You should find the vector is faster.

Answer (score 2):

After analysing assembly generated by VC++ for these two cases, here is what I found. Compiler inlined practically everything and generated very similar loops for initialization after memory allocation. In case of vector inner loop looks like this:

```
013E3FC0  test        eax,eax  
013E3FC2  je          std::_Uninit_def_fill_n<vec2 *,unsigned int,vec2,std::allocator<vec2>,vec2>+19h (13E3FC9h)  
013E3FC4  mov         dword ptr [eax],edx  
013E3FC6  mov         dword ptr [eax+4],esi  
013E3FC9  add         eax,8  
013E3FCC  dec         ecx  
013E3FCD  jne         std::_Uninit_def_fill_n<vec2 *,unsigned int,vec2,std::allocator<vec2>,vec2>+10h (13E3FC0h)
```

where `edx` and `esi` registers were zerroed outside of the loop:

```
00013FB5  xor         edx,edx  
00013FB7  xor         esi,esi  
00013FB9  lea         esp,[esp]
```

In case of `new[]` inner loop looks like this:

```
009F1800  mov         dword ptr [ecx],0  
009F1806  mov         dword ptr [ecx+4],0  
009F180D  add         ecx,8  
009F1810  dec         edx  
009F1811  jns         main+30h (9F1800h)
```

Differences are very insignificant, a few more instructions in case of `vector`, but probably also faster `mov`s from registers. Since in most real-life cases, constructors do a lot more than assigning zeros, this difference can hardly be noticeable at all. So the value of this testing is questionable.

Comment: Interesting; thanks for this.  The first code is obviously inefficient; the `jne` goes back to the `test` + `je` which cannot possibly evaluate to true...  So it could have made the `jne` loop back to the first `mov`.  Also, are you sure the move of a zero constant is faster than a register?

Comment: @Nemo: I don't know if the actual `mov` performance is easy to analyse on modern processors. But checking my old Intel book, 386 did `mov mem, reg` and `mov mem, immed` both in 2 cycles.